# Owned Entity with Polymorphism EF core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Bonjour

I need some help to understand how we map OwnedEntity when they are polymorph.
I have this inventory hierarchy of records that are linked to a product class .

```
public abstract record Inventory
{
    protected Inventory() { }
}

public record NoProductInventory : Inventory
{
    public NoProductInventory()
    {
    }
}

public sealed record ProductLevelInventory : Inventory
{
    public int Stock { get; private set; } = default!;
    public int LowStock { get; private set; } = default!;
    protected ProductLevelInventory() {}
    public ProductLevelInventory(int stock, int lowStock) : base()
    {
        Stock = stock;
        LowStock = lowStock;
    }
}

public sealed record VariantLevelInventory : Inventory
{
    public int Stock { get; private set; } = default!;
    public int LowStock { get; private set; } = default!;
    public int SomeOption { get; private set; }
    protected VariantLevelInventory() {}
    public VariantLevelInventory(int stock, int lowStock) : base()
    {
        Stock = stock;
        LowStock = lowStock;
    }
}
```

The Product class Definition

```
public class Product
{
    ....
    public Inventory Inventory { get; private set; } = default!;
    ....
}
```

I am using fluent API in order to mapped those entities

```
public class ProductEntityTypeBuilder : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Product>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Product> builder)
    {
        builder.OwnsOne(x => x.Inventory, bld =>
        {
            bld.ToTable("Inventories");
            // bld.Property(x => x.TrackInventory).IsRequired();
            bld.Property(x => x.Stock).IsRequired(false);
            bld.Property(x => x.LowStock).IsRequired(false);
            // bld.Property(x => x.InventoryTrackType).IsRequired(false);
        });
    }
}
```

My question is: how can I tell EF which Inventory record to use? I don't want to use casting to figure out what kind of inventory a product has.

Good Day !

Comment: For non-trivial database designs I think it's best to do your `CREATE TABLE` statements by hand instead of hoping that EF will somehow get it right. There's still a _lot_ of data-modelling scenarios that EF Core 6 still doesn't support (e.g. `1:1`). YMMV.

Comment: @Dai. wdym EF Core doesn't support 1:1? [Other relationship patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#other-relationship-patterns)

Comment: @Tseng That's not true `1:1`: it's really `1:0..1`. EF doesn't support true `1:1` because that requires you to use either really _gnarly_ DB designs in SQL Server (i.e. with `VIEW`s and `INSTEAD OF INSERT` triggers) - or use an RDMBs that supports Deferred Constraints (...for which I think so-far EF only supports PostgreSQL) - but the EF team don't want to make SQL Server look bad so they don't really advertise that feature much.

Answer (score 2):

Owned entities are meant to be used as value types, containing and encapsulate multiple values which belong together and don't have a meaning on their own, i.e. `MonetaryAmount` which consists of a `Amount` and a `Currency` property.

You can't do this right now. If you need hierarchies, you have to convert your owned types into entities and use it as regular navigation properties on the base type which are distinguished via a discriminator.

Owned types do not support inheritance [Owned Types: Shortcommings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities#current-shortcomings)

> #### Current shortcomings
>
> Owned entity types cannot have inheritance hierarchies

Answer (score -1):

**Something Similar**

I achieved something similar to 'owned' with polymorphic entities with:

- Cascade delete
- Polymorphic child entities are always included
- Cannot load polymorphic (child) entities directly

Something I noticed it cannot do is: changes to the pseudo-owned child entity do NOT trigger tracking on the parent. So adding or removing an element to the parent's List field may not trigger an update.

Specifics for an example of a `Meeting` that has multiple `ActionItem`s that can be either 'Simple' or 'Complex'.

`BaseActionItem` has a required foreign key which causes cascade delete:

```
[Required]
[MaxLength(GUID_LENGTH)]
public string MeetingId { get; set; }
```

Set up relation with `AutoInclude`:

```
    // Causes a foreign key and supports the 'AutoInclude' below
    modelBuilder.Entity<Meeting>()
        .HasMany(m => m.ActionItems);
    
    // makes it behave like it's 'owned'
    modelBuilder.Entity<Meeting>()
        .Navigation(m => m.ActionItems)
        .AutoInclude();
```

The action items do NOT have a `DbSet<BaseActionItem>` property on the `DbContext`. The entity is introduced only in `OnConfigure()`:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<BaseActionItem>()
        .ToTable("ActionItem")
        .HasDiscriminator(i => i.Discriminator);

    modelBuilder.Entity<ComplexActionItem>();
    modelBuilder.Entity<SimpleActionItem>();
```